# Algorithm to connect curves with a single stroke without intersection

Tags: c#, voronoi, grasshopper

What are some algorithms or methods to connect pattern/Voronoi curves with a single stroke that cannot intersect? I have a robot that is extruding material, and it cannot easily stop like regular Filament printer. I would like to know how to generate a path that connects vertices without intersecting itself. I want to use this system for different pattern and geometries.  [[vornoi 3D Printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW4NE.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhkOo.jpg)

I populated a Voronoi pattern and used a C# script to connect the centrepoints. The script is solving the TSP using a brute-force approach by exploring all possible combinations of point swaps to find the shortest route. But it seems that this algorithm does not quite work as it cuts through geometry that it should not cut double. Can somebody help?

```
public class Script_Instance : GH_ScriptInstance
{
#region Utility functions
  /// <summary>Print a String to the [Out] Parameter of the Script component.</summary>
  /// <param name="text">String to print.</param>
  private void Print(string text) { /* Implementation hidden. */ }
  /// <summary>Print a formatted String to the [Out] Parameter of the Script component.</summary>
  /// <param name="format">String format.</param>
  /// <param name="args">Formatting parameters.</param>
  private void Print(string format, params object[] args) { /* Implementation hidden. */ }
  /// <summary>Print useful information about an object instance to the [Out] Parameter of the Script component. </summary>
  /// <param name="obj">Object instance to parse.</param>
  private void Reflect(object obj) { /* Implementation hidden. */ }
  /// <summary>Print the signatures of all the overloads of a specific method to the [Out] Parameter of the Script component. </summary>
  /// <param name="obj">Object instance to parse.</param>
  private void Reflect(object obj, string method_name) { /* Implementation hidden. */ }
#endregion

#region Members
  /// <summary>Gets the current Rhino document.</summary>
  private readonly RhinoDoc RhinoDocument;
  /// <summary>Gets the Grasshopper document that owns this script.</summary>
  private readonly GH_Document GrasshopperDocument;
  /// <summary>Gets the Grasshopper script component that owns this script.</summary>
  private readonly IGH_Component Component;
  /// <summary>
  /// Gets the current iteration count. The first call to RunScript() is associated with Iteration==0.
  /// Any subsequent call within the same solution will increment the Iteration count.
  /// </summary>
  private readonly int Iteration;
#endregion

  /// <summary>
  /// This procedure contains the user code. Input parameters are provided as regular arguments,
  /// Output parameters as ref arguments. You don't have to assign output parameters,
  /// they will have a default value.
  /// </summary>
  private void RunScript(List<Point3d> pts, int n, ref object A)
  {
    pts.Add(pts[0]);
    var route = pts.ToArray();
    var shortest = Length(route);
    for (var k = 0; k < n; k++)
      for (var i = 1; i < route.Length - 1; i++)
        for (var j = i + 1; j < route.Length; j++)
          route = Swap(route, ref shortest, i, j);
    A = route;
  }

  // <Custom additional code> 
  double Length(Point3d[] route)
  {
    var d = 0.0;
    for(var i = 0; i < route.Length - 1; i++)
      d += route[i].DistanceTo(route[i + 1]);
    return d;
  }
  Point3d[] Swap(Point3d[] route, ref double shortest, int i, int j)
  {
    var swapped = (Point3d[]) route.Clone();
    Array.Reverse(swapped, i, j - i);
    var len = Length(swapped);
    if (len < shortest)
    {
      shortest = len;
      return swapped;
    }
    return route;
  }
  // </Custom additional code> 
}
```

Comment: So, you have some kind of shape that can be described as a graph, right? And you want to traverse all the edges exactly once? That sounds like the "[Seven Bridges of Königsberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg)", a famous problem that is proved to have no solution.

Comment: @JonasH Thanks you for your input!  the problem does involve traversing edges, but I guess it's more a Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP) applied to a Voronoi pattern. My goal is to connect the Voronoi cells' with a single stroke. The uniqueness of my problem lies in ensuring that each cell is connected only once while navigating the geometry of the Voronoi layout. If you have any insights or suggestions on algorithms that can handle these specific constraints, I'd greatly appreciate your input!

Comment: Please remove the `rhino` tag on this question, because this is not about `rhino`